# Intersection of two cell arrays of strings in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell, intersection

I have two cell arrays, X and Y. Each cell array is made up of strings : i.e, X{i} is a string for all i, and so is Y{i}. I would like to find the intersection of the two cell arrays, (presumably a third cell array} that has the strings common to both X and Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might a single function that does this - I don't remember. But you can do it pretty easily with `ismember`:

```
a = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
b = {'b', 'd', 'a'};
intersection = a(ismember(a, b));
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a single function that does this:  `intersect`

For example:

```
    >> X = {'a', 'b'; 'c', 'd'};
    >> Y = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    >> Z = intersect(X, Y)

    Z = 

        'c'    'd'
```